# Include Jekyll template ONLY if it exists

Tags: ruby, jekyll

There's [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26410279/2193396) in another question, but it doesn't meet my needs.

I need to `include` a template in `_includes` **if and only if it exists.**

Comment: Seems it shall use plugin https://stackoverflow.com/a/40776937/4058484

Answer (score 2):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14667270/shopify-liquid-how-can-i-conditionally-include-snippets-in-shopify-liquid) might come handy for you.

The basic idea is to place the *include* block within a *capture* block in order to save its content to a variable.

If the template doesn't exists, the variable will contain an error message rather than the templates content, otherwise you're good to go to include the actual template.

```
{% capture the_snippet_content %}{% include the_snippet %}{% endcapture %}
{% unless the_snippet_content contains "Liquid error" %}
    {{the_snippet}}
{% endunless %}
```

Comment: When I try to use this the Liquid error causes the project to fail to build, capture does not seem to capture exceptions.