# Using Jekyll how can I check if file exist in my folder?

Tags: jekyll, liquid

I have an `_includes` folder, and within it I have `nav` subfolder containing a `nav.html` file.

I've been trying to check if `nav.html` exists in `nav`. If it does, I want to include that `nav.html` file. If it doesnt exist, there will be a default `nav` for my template.

Here's the code I have right now:

```
{% for static_file in site.static_files %}
    {% if static_file.path == '/nav.html' %}
        {% include nav.html %}
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Hope you guys can help me out.

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

I am not able to find the solution using existing liquid tags so I solved this by using a plugin with a custom liquid tag.

```
{% capture fileExists %}{% file_exists _includes/nav/custom/nav.html %}{% endcapture %}
{% if fileExists=="true" %}
    {% include /nav/custom/nav.html %}
{% else %}
    {% include /nav/default/nav.html %}
{% endif %}
```

See [GitHub Repo](https://github.com/michaelx/jekyll_file_exists)